# RabbitMQ and unstable connection

Tags: php, connection, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ with PHP (via php-amqplib). But server, where my consumer is running, has really unstable connection. So, each 15-30 minutes consumer losts connection to the remote rabbitmq server, but php daemon still running. Is there any solution to handle lossy connections in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use heartbeats for the connection but if the problem continues after that you'd better log the connection errors in order to verify what's going on with the connectivity.

Comment: can you refer to a good example where heartbeat is used... I tried to use it and it is inside a protected function... so had to hack AMQP implementation... but could not find a place where I can just pass it as a parameter in either a constructor or function and let the code do the rest.

Comment: @Nasaralla I haven't used php to connect to rabbit. I used NET but if the library you are using is similar to C# client library you should be able to set heartbeat value in a connection factory. 
See http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.0.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.0.1-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.html

Comment: Continue... 
@Nasaralla 
If the php library you are using is not providing a similar connection construction I would suggest you to ask to the author to  support customized heartbeats since it is a very important connection setting. And finally as you said your last chance would be to hack the library. I hope this helps